# PHP/MySQL: How to verify properly escaped data?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, quotes

Well, on my php pages I am escaping in this manner:

```
$title = "Jack's Long 'Shoes'";
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$go = mysql_query("INSERT INTO titles (title) VALUES '$title'");
```

Then when I view this data via phpmyadmin, the data appears as it were before it was escaped, ie `Jack's Long 'Shoes'`

I was under the impression that it would look like:
`Jack\s Long \Shoes\`

Are the slashes supposed to actually be printed inside the mysql database field?

Comment: no you will not see the slashes when viewing the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The escapes vanish once they pass into the data tables. That's the whole points of escaping data - it's like stuffing a letter into an envelope. The letter stays in the envelope (escaped) during its journey through the postal system. Once it gets to its destination (the database storage medium), it's removed from the envelope and stored in its original form.

If the escaping (envelope) was stored along with the letter, you'd have to UNESCAPE (open the envelope) it each time you pulled the letter out of the database.

For databases, the escaping serves to "hide" SQL metacharacters from the query parser. Once the data's passed through the parser and has been written into the DB, the escapes are no longer necessary. The db's own internal handlers knows what is data and what is sql commands, so the artificial divisions created by the escapes are no longer necessary at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Certain characters must exist so that the statement can be understood.

For example, in PHP, when you have, $var = "The other day, someone said, \"Hello!\""; you don't expect the \ to exist in the output string.  Escaping in SQL is the same concept.  The escape characters are there to mark special characters as literal, not to actually show up.